# Eslint error when I use babel alias on nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, eslint, next.js

I added the `module-resolver` plugin to **.babelrc** to be able to use aliases in my nextjs project.

```
"plugins": [
    [
        "module-resolver",
        {
             "root": [
             "./"
             ],
             "alias": {
                "components": "./app/components",
                "pages": "./app/pages",
                "themes": "./app/themes"
             }
        }
    ]
]
```

Everything work well but since I added this configuration, my eslint configuration generate import/no-unresolved errors.

> [eslint] Unable to resolve path to module 'components/HOC'. [import/no-unresolved]

To fix that, I tried to update my **.eslintrc.json** settings like that:

```
"settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "components": "./app/components",
      "pages": "./app/pages",
      "themes": "./app/themes"
    }  
},
```

However, this new configuration have no effect. I want to clear this problem properly, do you have an idea to properly fix that problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add this setting on your `jsconfig.json` (`tsconfig.json` for TypeScript)
reference:
https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver#editors-autocompletion

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "components": ["./app/components"],
      "pages": ["./app/pages"],
      "themes": ["./app/themes"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's helpful!